# How do I create a route with a query string?

Tags: 8, routes

I have tried a few things and I cannot manage to make this working.

My route is the following.

```
    amu_hal.publicationsPerYear:
      path: '/publications/{year}'
      defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\amu_hal\Controller\AmuHalController::publicationPerYear'
        _title: 'publicationPerYear'
        year: 2016
        route_parameters:
          url: 'default'
      requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

The code for the controller is the following.

```
    public function publicationPerYear($year,$url) {
      $url=urldecode($url);
      $url .='&fq=producedDateY_i:' . $year;

      try {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $url);
        $content = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        // ...
      }
    }
```

The request http://mysite/publications/2016?url=https%3A%2F%2FmyWS%2Fsearch%2F%3Frows%3D5%26sort%3DproducedDate_tdate%2Bdesc%26fl%3Dtitle_s%2Cen_title_s%2Clabel_s%2Cen_label_s%2CdocType_s%2CauthIdHal_s%2ChalId_s%2CstructId_i%2Curi_s%2Ckeyword_s%2Cen_keyword_s%2CauthLastNameFirstName_s%2CjournalTitle_s%26fq%3DauthFullName_t%3A(%22M%22+OR+%22e+d%22) gives the following error:

> RuntimeException: Controller "Drupal\amu_hal\Controller\AmuHalController::publicationPerYear()" requires that you provide a value for the "$url" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one). in Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerResolver->doGetArguments() (line 165 of /var/aegir/platforms/drupal8-dev/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/ControllerResolver.php).

Comment: Is the yaml format valid? http://www.yamllint.com/ - always worth asking.

Comment: nice tool , yes it is valid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot create a route based on the query string, but you still can retrieve query string values in your code:

```
amu_hal.publicationsPerYear:
  path: '/publications/{year}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\amu_hal\Controller\AmuHalController::publicationPerYear'
    _title: 'publicationPerYear'
    year: 2016
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

```
public function publicationPerYear($year) {
  $url = \Drupal::request()->query->get('url') ?: 'default';
}
```

Comment: as a note i have found the yml 'route_parameters ' in the core menu_test.links.menu.yml !?

Comment: As I wrote, you should let get request object get injected, not use \Drupal::request()

Comment: Does injection has any other purpose than unit testing? I don't really understand why Drupal's static services must not be used.

Answer (score 9):

Meanwhile (Drupal 8.6) it's possible to declare query parameters in drupal routes. In a mymodule.routing.yml file, to declare a query variable "token", do it like this:

```
mymodule.mailcommitter:
  path: '/mailcheck/{uid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ProfilController::checkMailCommit'
    _title: 'commit mail'
  options:
      query:
        token: ""
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Then, you build an url by route like so

```
'url' => Url::fromRoute('mymodule.mailcommitter', ['uid' => 1], ['query' => ['token' => 'hello']])
```

The result is an uri like `/mailcheck/1/?token=hello`

Also check this doc: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes

Comment: Where did you find the query option for `*.routing.yml` in the linked doc? I could find it only for `*.links.menu.yml`, which would be another option to build URLs like in your code example: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-menu-links

Comment: @4k4 - you are right again. The link is misleading for the query-option topic.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we support passing a query argument through like that.

Just get the request object with `Request $request` and then get the url from there with `$request->query->get('url');`

---

#### Sample method

```php
  /**
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
   */
  public function download(Request $request) {
    dd($request->query->get('url'));
  }
```