# Can I require a query string parameter?

Tags: 8, routes

In a route, say `password_recover/?code=XXX`

How can I make `code`a required parameter? i don't have control over the system that appends the parameter to the url.

Comment: This seems to indicate that you can't. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229406/how-to-create-a-route-with-query-string

Comment: Though you may be able to fake it with a custom access callback. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes