# Add '?' and '=' characters to query string

Tags: 8, routes

I'm trying to pass '?' and '=' symbols to a page using routing.yml

```
company.calc:
  path: '/form?company={nid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
    _title: 'Calc'
 requirements:
   _permission: 'access content'
```

but the symbols are transcoded to HTML-entities. It looks like `form%3Fcompany%3D%3Fcompany%3D18141` and leads to page 404.

Any ideas how to pass the string like

```
/form?company=1234
```

? This string is necessary to prepopulate the form's field.

Find the same question [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-02-21/query-strings-in-drupal-8) but no reply, no solution :(.

Comment: This is the correct way, then they are decoded when the form receives the get parameters.

Comment: Yes, it is. But the path leads to page-404. If I replace the transcoded entities the page is good (not 404). Is there a way to switch off the transcoding?

Comment: I thought you want to pass '?' within a query parameter. You should change the question title to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229406/how-to-create-a-route-with-query-string

Comment: Don not specify query parameters in the path - element, check my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You declare query parameters in drupal routes in a mymodule.routing.yml file like this:

```
mymodule.mailcommitter:
  path: '/mailcheck/{uid}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ProfilController::checkMailCommit'
    _title: 'commit mail'
  options:
      query:
        token: ""
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Then, you build an url by route like so

```
'url' => Url::fromRoute('mymodule.mailcommitter', ['uid' => 1], ['query' => ['token' => 'hello']])
```

Also check this doc: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes

Comment: Wow! You're my hero for the rest of the day!!

Comment: Great answer, you have to add the query parameter to the route when building the url. BTW I don't think the query option in the route definition has any effect, query parameters are transferred from the super globals to the request object and are available even before routing and are not checked in route matching.

Comment: @4k4 your right, the declaration in routing.yml makes no difference and options is a generic array in the route object - but it's nice to have a declaration anyway :-)